# How to make a deadlock safe async library method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I publish an open source .Net library. Is there a deadlock safe way to expose methods that need to do long running tasks, such as DNS lookups?

In the example below `f1` and `f2` represent the library functions accessible from a nuget package. The `Task.Delay` call represents some long running network task, such as a DNS lookup. The library methods, `f1` and `f2`, depending on the needs of the caller, may be called as fire and forget or they may want to wait for completion.

My question is how can a library method be written so the caller is not at a risk of a deadlock?

The comments next to the call show which ones deadlock. `f1` is the best but the caller would have to be aware of the need for `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Deadlock
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Form _form;

        public static async Task Main()
        {
            _form = new Form();

            Func<int, Task> f1 = (i) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.Second}: f1 {i}");

                return Task.Delay(1000)
                .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.Second}: f1 {i} finished"));
            };

            Func<int, Task> f2 = async (i) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.Second}: f2 {i}");

                await Task.Delay(1000)
                .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.Second}: f2 {i} finished"));
            };

            var syncCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            Console.WriteLine($"sync ctx ? {syncCtx != null}");

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                _ = f1(i);                         // OK.
                //_ = f2(i);                         // OK.
                //await f1(i);                       // Deadlock.
                //await f1(i).ConfigureAwait(false); // OK.
                //await f2(i);                       // Deadlock.
                //await f2(i).ConfigureAwait(false); // Deadlock.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.Second}: Finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for the `ContinueWith` inside `f1` and `f2`? This method has been largely become obsolete after the introduction of async/await.

Comment: This example leaves ***a lot*** to be desired and is a little convoluted. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` when appropriate. However, usually the deadlock is the concern of the user of your library. There is no real way to protect the user from themselves

Comment: @sipwiz As TheGeneral has pointed out the deadlock concern is coming from the users of your library. For example if you use this library from a Console application, where there is no SynchronizationContext ([1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/)) then it will behave differently than in WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a deadlock safe way to expose methods that need to do long running tasks, such as DNS lookups?

Yes:

1. Use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`.
2. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for every `await`. There are analyzers available that will enforce this and make sure you don't miss one by mistake.

> In the example below

The example code is flawed, because it is using a UI `SynchronizationContext` that does not do message pumping. You should create an actual WinForms/WPF app to run these tests, and then you'll see that the deadlock behavior is different than the example code in this question.